# Recommended way to wire a serial port on a server?

Tags: serial

I need to connect some Dell servers to a WTI TSM-40 serial port console.  The serial console uses RJ45 connectors, and the Dells have DB9.  I have DB9-RJ45 adapters (the ones you can customize with whatever pin layout you need).

So the question is this: Is there a recommended way to hook these up?  Should I get straight-through serial cables and handle the null-ing inside of the adapter, or setup the adapters as straight-through, and get crossover serial cables?

This delves into the arcane world of serial and telecom equipment and things like DTE/DCE, which I'm not that familiar with.  Are there any standards for this sort of thing?  I've noticed that Monoprice seems to distinguish straight-through cables as used for data and crossover cables for voice.

P.S. Dells are running Linux and this is for a serial console on them.

Answer (score 4):

I ***highly*** recommend the [Yost Serial Device Wiring Standard](http://yost.com/computers/RJ45-serial/).

From that page:

> Here is a scheme which solves four of the six RS-232 hassles:
>
> 1. All cable connectors are the same sex (male).
> 2. All cable connectors are of the same type (RJ-45).
> 3. There is no distinction between DTE and DCE plugs and sockets.
> 4. You can mass-terminate the connector cables with a crimping tool.
>
> The other two hassles that remain are:
>
> 1. Baud rate matching.
> 2. Flow control problems.
>
> All of your cables are wired the same and have the same connectors.
>
> - No more null-modems or "null-terminal" adapters.
> - No more changing pins on cable connectors.
> - No more building special cables for each kind of hookup.
> - No more soldering or messing with pins on cables.

Be sure to see the section on conflicting RJ-45 pinouts.

Comment: Is the Yost Serial Device Wiring Standard the same thing as a "Rollover" cable? Wikipedia says that [they are the same thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_cable), but I can't always trust Wikipedia.
Yost Serial Device Wiring Standard

Comment: @Stefan: The Yost cable is the one on the left in [my answer to your question](http://serverfault.com/questions/181220/flat-8-conductor-cables-for-a-serial-console-what-are-they-called/181241#181241) (labeled "crossed"). Yes it's a "rollover" cable. Pin 1 on one end is connected to pin 8 on the other.

Answer (score 3):

The pinouts should be handled inside the adapter, or at least that's what we're doing. That way standard pre-crimped Cat5 can be used to provide the cable. Yes, it may involve figuring out how to tweak the adapter (I went several rounds coming up with a similar RS232 adapter for an older Liebert UPS, so I know). But it'll ease things in the long run.

Answer (score -2):

Google "RS-232" and that should really tell you everything you need to know as far as standards are concerned.

Comment: What makes you think he didn't Google this already? SF exists to help provide answers, not just direct people to Google. I have 8 RS-232 adapters on my desk-- each is different and not interchangeable-- RS-232 can be arcane and non-trivial.

Comment: You're right.  I guess I should have read the question more carefully.